# How can we track customer transaction usage within a single App ID?

Tags: here-api

We're planning to develop an application/product that uses HERE's JavaScript API to display interactive maps. We plan to use one App ID. We will then allow our customers to install our end-product (the project where the HERE maps is part of) and use the maps through our App ID. We have a license agreement with HERE based on "transaction billing" (not asset based) and we would like to track our different customer's map usage such that we can bill then for the transactions that they are using, and which we are providing, via our App ID, on their behalf.

So, given we want to use the same App ID for all customers, is there a way for us to track the transactions/usage by each customer?

Comment: Highly doubt that you'd be able to do this with just the APP ID, I suggest getting a different token to each user to identify them and distribute the bill based on their usage. But the tracking and calculation would be on your end.

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting! When you say token, what sort of token are you referring to? Yet another App ID (because that is an option, in theory, even though it could be cumbersome, or even impossible, with hundreds of customers)? We're planning to use App IDs together with API Key Credentials, by the way.

Comment: I think you have two options here: 
1. generate a new AppID for each user
2. you keep track of all the calls on your own, so you'd have to create the backend to support that.

Answer (score 1):

We provide the billing details for the individual user account that has registered for Here Location Services. Managing at application level requires writing logic at your end as we are not yet providing module for this calculation. you can assign either specific app ID for each count, or calculate API hits at user level to check the transactions made for each account.

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting! Are there any plans to make it easier for us to track user or customer usage other than the above? Also, about writing our own logic, we could do that, and it would work for geocoding, where we, with our own code, explicitly call your geocoding service. However, how can we write code to handle requests done by your JavaScript map APIs? Is there a way to "hook" into the calls made by the APIs perhaps?